# How Do I Update The Widget's TextViewText From A Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget

I am trying to update my widget's TextView Text from a BroadcastReceiver on ClickPendingIntent. I am not having much luck. Can I please get some help with this? In my ActionReceiver.class which extends BroadcastReceiver, I know that I need to update the widget after changing the textview text. I am not sure how to do that. Unfortunately, I can't use statics without crashing the app and widget. Here is my code...

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mywidget">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name=".MyWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/my_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="locked">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".ActionReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/default_tv_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myTV"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/default_et_text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        tools:ignore="Autofill" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/myET"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my_widget.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Widget</string>
    <string name="default_tv_text">Hello World!</string>
    <string name="default_et_text">Enter Something To Change The Text Above.</string>
    <string name="button_text">OK</string>
    <string name="appwidget_text">EXAMPLE</string>
    <string name="appwidget_text_changed">Hello World!</string>
    <string name="add_widget">Add widget</string>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.class

```
package com.example.mywidget;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;
    EditText et;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.myTV);
        et = findViewById(R.id.myET);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String getEditText = et.getText().toString();

                if (!getEditText.isEmpty()) {
                    tv.setText(getEditText);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Text Changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyWidget.class

```
package com.example.mywidget;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;


public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        Intent actionIntent = new Intent(context, ActionReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pi);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

}
```

ActionReceiver.class

```
package com.example.mywidget;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        CharSequence getNewText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text_changed);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, getNewText); // The widget needs to be updated from here with something like this updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

My Updated MyWidget.class

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

   public void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                       int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        Intent actionIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pi);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }

    @Override

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AppWidgetManager appWM = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
        int[] appWIDs = appWM.getAppWidgetIds(myWidget);

        CharSequence getNewText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text_changed);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, getNewText);

        if (appWIDs == null && appWIDs.length > 0) {
            onUpdate(context, appWM, appWIDs);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

It's still not working for me. When I click the textview on the widget, it just launches the app. I'm trying to get the textview to change the default word "Example" to "Hello World" when the textview is clicked on. I've been trying for hours figuring this out.

Comment: Call `AppWidgetManager.getInstance()` to get an `AppWidgetManager`. Then, call `updateAppWidget()` on the `AppWidgetManager`.

Comment: Hey CommonsWare! Do you mean like this? 

AppWidgetManager appWM = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), MyWidget.class);
        int[] appWIds = appWM.getAppWidgetIds(myWidget);
        if (appWIds != null && appWIds.length > 0) {
            onUpdate(context, appWM, appWIds);
        }

Comment: Something along those lines, yes. You do not need `getApplicationContext()` in either place. And note that you are updating all instances of your app widget to be the same content, which may or may not be what the user wants.

Comment: Ok I removed the `getApplicationContext()` from both. Now it just says context. I am planning on having several OnClickPendingIntent eventually. So, I will need each TextViewText to update as the user calls for the update upon click on each.

Comment: Still no luck. I've been trying. I don't know. I'm going to cave in. What's the answer?